# Does .where('field IN (?)', array) always return records in order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Does the query:

```
company_ids = [2,6,15,1,3]

@people = Person.where("company_id IN (?)", company_ids)
```

**always** return `@people` sorted by the `company_ids` array?

If not, would it be best practice to add an `.order()` like:

```
c_ids = company_ids.collect{|c_id| "company_id = #{c_id}"}

@people = Person.where("company_id IN (?)", company_ids).order( c_ids.join(',') )
```

Comment: If ordering is not specified explicitly, then it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm trying to avoid performance overhead of doing an unnecessary sort. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If you _need_ records in order, then you better sort them. Or get woken up in the middle of the night when production breaks. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Do you know if the ordering method I'm using above would work for an array of ids? Thanks :)

Comment: I doubt that very much :)

Comment: Any idea what would? I need to sort `@people` such that `company_id` is ordered according to `company_ids`.

Comment: Your safest bet would be sorting in the app. It's not the most performant way, probably.

Answer (score 0):

```
@people = Person.where("company_id IN (?)", company_ids).order(id: :desc).map(&:id)
```

Haven't tested can you please try this.

Comment: You're not ordering `company_id` by the given array, you're ordering by descending `id` then collecting those IDs.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't.

You can do it in SQL but the query syntax will depend on the database you are using. For MySQL something like this should work:

```
@people = Person.where("company_id IN (?)", company_ids).order("field(company_id, #{company_ids.join(',')})")
```

I don't think there is an easy way to do it in PostgreSQL but unless you have millions of rows, you can just do the sorting in Ruby:

```
index = Person.where("company_id IN (?)", company_ids).group_by(&:company_id)
@people = company_ids.map{|id| index[id]}.flatten
```

---EDIT---

That's how you can do the same in PostgreSQL:

```
Person.where("company_id IN (?)", company_ids).order("CASE #{company_ids.map{|id| "WHEN company_id='#{id}' THEN #{company_ids.index(id)}"}.join(' ')} END;")
```

Comment: I need `@people` as a sorted relation, and this is for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Added a small monstrosity of a PostgreSQL query that should do what you need.

Answer (score -1):

```
@people = Person.where("company_id IN (?)", company_ids).order("company_id")
```

This will ensure that you always have @people in the order by company_id. Please comment if you are expecting something else.

Comment: This orders `Person` according to ascending company_id. I need the order of company_id to match the `company_ids` array exactly.

Comment: oh cool, for that you just have add "sort_by", below is the code.
`@people = Person.where("company_id IN (?)", company_ids).sort_by{ |x| company_ids.index x.company_id }`